# Installing Windows 10 Bootcamp on 27 iMac (2015): USB 3.0 problem

Tags: macos, imac, bootcamp, windows

I'm trying to install Windows 10 on my iMac. I've gotten to the part where Windows setup asks for the bootcamp drivers, before Windows is installed ("Collecting information"). I've tried having the bootcamp drivers on both a usb 2.0 and a usb 3.0 external hard drive, and I still get the following error:

"No device drivers were found. Make sure that the installation media contains the correct drivers, and then click ok"

[I've digged a bit](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3b4eeaf3-e7c4-4057-821d-f3a45451374f/no-device-drivers-were-found-make-sure-that-the-installation-media-contains-the-correct-drivers?forum=w7itprohardware) and found that the issue is a USB 3.0 issue, according to many. All the iMac USB's are 3.0, so what is the solution here ? I don't have an SD card or a thunderbolt drive.

Comment: I must be missing something. I thought you have to use the Boot Camp Assistant to create a USB flash drive containing the files from the Windows 10 iso and the Boot Camp Support Software. If so, then why don't you copy the Boot Camp Support Software to the internal disk before installing Windows 10? That way you would not need to get them from a USB drive later in the installation process.

Comment: that's what I ended up doing. it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Actually if you look on Apples website they have updated about bootcamp 6.0.1 on El Capitan.  All 2015 models do not need a USB stick to put Windows 10 ISO in.  All 2015 Mac models from Macbook, Air, Pro, Mac Pro, and iMac do not need USB with Windows 10 ISO.  You can simply download Windows 10 ISO file, put it on desktop, open bootcamp.  Apple website says that all 2015 Macs have the install Mac bootcamp uploader files for Windows within a private partition that uploads after installing Windows and gets to start menu desktop.  If you want to read more of what I just told go to https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201468  It states right on there that 2015 Macs do not need USB for Windows 10 install on bootcamp anymore.